# Is it possible to tell brew to include all optional dependencies?

Tags: homebrew

Is there a flag or way that will tell brew to include all optional dependencies? Some of these formula have tons of "--with" flags and it would be nice to be able to just specify "--with-ALL" I read the man page and couldn't find anything. I'm pretty new to brew so please excuse my ignorance if this is something really obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a shell function like (put this into a file anywhere you like -- it does not need a file extension):

```
function brew-alloptions () {
    brew install $1 $(brew options $1 | grep -E '^--with-' - | tr '\n' ' ')
}
```

Source this file:

```
% source path/to/source/file
```

Use it like this:

```
brew-alloptions name
```

The ruby equivalent (the part that gathers the options):

```
`brew options vim`.lines.to_a.select { |item| item =~ /^--with-/ }.map(&:strip)
```

Where `vim` is the target formula.